# drupal 6: write to 2 different tables for user account registration form

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-hooks

```
function Mymodule_user($op,&$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'register':
      $result = db_query("SELECT id,name FROM {sites} ORDER BY name");
      while($row=db_fetch_array($result)) {
        $sites[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
      }

      $form['site_select'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Select your site'),
        '#options' => $sites,
      )
      return $form;

    case 'insert':
      //How to take the $form values from above and use in my query to
      //write to my own table while writing to the standard 'users' table?
      db_query("INSERT INTO {another_table} (site_name) VALUES ('%s')",
               $form['site_select']);
);
```

When the user hits the SUBMIT button when creating a standard Drupal account, how do I pass my custom field value of $form['site_select'] to my case 'insert' so that I can write this to 'another_table'.  The regular user data such as username and password needs to continue to write to the default 'users' table.

Q: Why not just let Drupal serialize and save your data to the 'users' table in the 'data' field as it normally does?

A: Because I want to be able to AJAX-ify and use autocomplete in another Drupal form, as well as query specific custom fields in  MySQL. MySQL cannot serialize/unserialize.  For example, "SELECT DISTINCT site_name FROM another_table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably gonna want to alter the user_register form in order to add your own callback function to that form's #submit property, like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_FORMID_alter().
 * @param $form
 * @param $form_state
 * @return void
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULEs_own_register_submit_callback_func';
}
```

And then in the callback you're going to have `$form_state` filled with whatever the user filled into the form (including the value for the extra site_select field element which you added in your hook_user implementation):

```
<?php
function MYMODULEs_own_register_submit_callback_func(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Do stuff with $form_state['values'], i.e $form_state['values']['site_select'], etc.
}
```

Comment: This works! But now is there a way so that these custom fields do NOT get written into the 'users' table in the 'data' field where it then gets serialized? I don't want the data in 2 places.  I moved the custom form field $form['site_select'] into the the Mymodule_form_user_register_alter(), but it still gets captured in the 'users' table in the 'data' field.

Comment: In that case, you should make sure your submit callback executes before the others, so instead of `$form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULEs_own_register_submit_callback_func';`, you would do `array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'MYMODULEs_own_register_submit_callback_func');` in your hook_form_FORMID_alter(). And then in the callback, after you do your thing, you could simply unset the value so that Drupal's normal callback never gets it, i.e. `unset($form_state['values']['site_select']);`

Comment: Excellent!  The data is now written to one table and the user account gets properly created in the 'users' table.  THANK YOU!